# Ajax cascading dropdownlist is not working for webservices methods

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Need to bind drop down value from another drop down value, web methods not 
firing even after added web reference, not showing any error.

I am getting error *method 500.

I am using visual studio and I have asp.net application as one project and a web service as another project.I am using web service in my asp.net application.

There is some sort of problem im my web service code. But i am unable to debug continuosly from asp.net application to web service.

I put break point both in application and web service but break point not activated in web service and it shows me connection error.

How can i do this while hosting on localhost?

*my country.aspx code*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ID="tsmcascading" runat="server">
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="cddstate" runat="server" ServicePath="~/cascadingdropdown.asmx"
                Category="stateid" ServiceMethod="addstate" TargetControlID="ddlstate" PromptText="select state"
                LoadingText="Loading...">
            </ajax:CascadingDropDown>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcity" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlcity"
                Category="stateid" ParentControlID="ddlstate" ServiceMethod="addcity" PromptText="select city"
                ServicePath="~/cascadingdropdown.asmx" LoadingText="Loading...">
            </ajax:CascadingDropDown>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*my webservice code (.asmx)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for cascadingdropdown
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class cascadingdropdown : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["addcontact"].ToString());
    public cascadingdropdown()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] addstate(string state, string city)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdstate = new SqlCommand("select stateid,statename from tblStates", con);
        cmdstate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter dastate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstate);
        DataSet dsstate = new DataSet();
        dastate.Fill(dsstate);
        con.Close();
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> statesnames = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dsstate.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string stateid = dtrow["stateid"].ToString();
            string statename = dtrow["statename"].ToString();
            statesnames.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(statename, stateid));
        }
        return statesnames.ToArray();

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] addcity(string state, string city)
    {
        int stateid;
        StringDictionary statedetails = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(state);
        stateid = Convert.ToInt32(statedetails["state"]);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdcity = new SqlCommand("select cityid,stateid,cityname from tblcities where stateid=@stateid", con);
        cmdcity.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateid", stateid);
        cmdcity.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter dacity = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcity);
        DataSet dscity = new DataSet();
        dacity.Fill(dscity);
        con.Close();
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> citynames = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dscity.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string cityid = dtrow["cityid"].ToString();
            string cityname = dtrow["cityname"].ToString();
            citynames.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(cityid, cityname));
        }
        return citynames.ToArray();
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard definition for functions used by AjaxControltoolkit cascading dropdown:

```
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] addState(String knownCategoryValues, String category, String contextKey)
{
...
}
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] addCity(String knownCategoryValues, String category, String contextKey)
{
...
}
```

Context key is not a mandatory parameter, you can ommit it if you do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have totally the same problem, i found a "tutorial" and i tried to fit it with my own code, but i couldn't get it to work i was also getting method 500 errors.

Try use 100% of this websites code

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/introduction-here-i-will-explain-how-to.html

It worked for me, i just fitted some of the code at a time.